# Creating a Mobile App/Website

Tags: android, mobile, jquery-mobile

I've created a website using ASP.net and C#. It's basically where students can login and view their marks/register courses/see schedules. It's connected to a SQL database which I have made in SQL server...

I want to be able to create a mobile version of this application. So what's more suitable, a mobile app or website? And which one will be easier?

I heard we use eclipse/java for making mobile apps.....

For the website, do we use a different framework, or is it the same asp.net and SQL for the database?

Comment: This question is the basis of a holy war nearly as bad as "Mac vs. PC" right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find a mobile website built with jQuery Mobile to be a good alternative to writing a native app.

Benefits Include:

- Consistent UI across platforms
- Smart, responsive scaling for larger
  devices (tablets, pc)
- Touch friendly default styles

I've put together a [jQuery Mobile Site Template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb8d369a-9397-4042-a9d7-f1c57148c717) on the Visual Studio Extension Gallery that you might find interesting for porting your existing .Net C# site.

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely recommend a mobile web application. The main advantage is that you have only to maintain one code base. Also it would be a very simple task since you could expose JSON from your asp.net website to http://jquerymobile.com/

There are many tutorials available and you do not have to bother about updating the application on users devices since it is a hypermedia based web app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with asp.net, but it seems like it'd be best to create a fluid, responsive front end for the web app on its existing framework. One web interface that scales neatly for a variety of devices, rather than authoring an API and various mobile apps for different platforms.

Great introduction to responsive (front-end) web design: http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/html5-versus-android-apps-or-web-for-mobile-development.html) is a great Google I/O 2011 session that I enjoyed watching on the topic of Native vs. Web approach. Link has the slides + videos. Enjoy and best of luck.